# Filebeat: How to export logs of specific pods

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

This is my filebeat config map.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: $${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

    setup.ilm.enabled: false
    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_host_metadata:

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
```

This sends logs from every pod to AWS ElasticSearch. How I can restrict it to send logs from specific pods by name and/or by the label?

Answer (score 0):

**add a `drop_event`field in the yaml file.**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
        - /var/log/containers/*.log
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: $${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

        - drop_event.when:
            not.equals:
                kubernetes.pod.name: [your_pod_name]
                # if you want to use label, replace it with kubernetes.labels.[your_label]

    setup.ilm.enabled: false
    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_host_metadata:

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
```